# Multiple text shadows in 2d canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

In CSS, I can chain multiple definitions in the `text-shadow` property to achieve effects such as glow:

```css
.green-glow {
    padding:20px 40px 40px;
    font-family:'Georgia';
    font-size:70px;
    background-color:#000;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #0f0, 0 0 70px #0f0, 0 0 80px #0f0, 0 0 100px #0f0, 0 0 150px #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-glow">glow</div>
```

I would like to achieve similar effects when drawing text on a canvas element using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText` but since shadow definitions are split among multiple properties (`shadowBlur`, `shadowColor`, etc.), it is not immediately obvious for me the adequate way to chain multiple shadows.

I can do multiple calls to `CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText`, one for each defined shadow as the following snippet shows...

```js
// get context
var ctx = document.querySelector('#test').getContext('2d');

// clear background to black
ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 150);

// common font attributes
ctx.font = "70px Georgia";
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

// apply multiple shadows

ctx.shadowColor = '#fff';
ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
ctx.fillText('glow', 50, 90);

ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.fillText('glow', 50, 90);

ctx.shadowBlur = 30;
ctx.fillText('glow', 50, 90);

ctx.shadowColor = '#0f0';
ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
ctx.fillText('glow', 50, 90);

ctx.shadowBlur = 70;
ctx.fillText('glow', 50, 90);

ctx.shadowBlur = 80;
ctx.fillText('glow', 50, 90);

ctx.shadowBlur = 100;
ctx.fillText('glow', 50, 90);

ctx.shadowBlur = 150;
ctx.fillText('glow', 50, 90);
```

```css
canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width="500" height="150"></canvas>
```

... and even though it doesn't quite look the same to me, it would be good enough for my purposes. But I am wondering about possible performance issues caused by those multiple calls to `fillText` and whether there is a more appropriate way to apply multiple text shadows on a canvas.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried at this scale, however if you want to make sure everything is rendered at the same time, you can always do all these calls on an off-screen canvas, and once that's rendered, position that canvas where you want it.

Comment: Thank you @AgataB. By "this scale" do you mean the dimensions of the drawing area in the provided snippets? My intention, if possible, is using two overlaid canvases up to full-screen if the user chooses so, one for 3D renderings using WebGL and another for 2D renderings on top, such as titles, cross-sections of 3D objects, etc. Should I be worried at that scale? Thanks again!

Comment: If someone has more detail on this, please correct me, but I would say you are fine for now. If you start noticing problems, look up canvas performance tricks - there's quite a few, but I think if you're using the above effect for just a handful of titles, your main source of performance issues will probably be the 3D rendering?