# How to create multiple shadows in a text (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this:

```
Letter.prototype.add = function (ctx) {
    ctx.shadowColor = "#44400";
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
}
```

I'd like to have shadows on all four sides and would like to add the following to the above definition:

```
ctx.shadowColor = "#333000";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: if you are looking for a ctx solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840513/multiple-text-shadows-in-2d-canvas

Answer (score 0):

The trick I would apply is to wrap a tag around another one, both having a shadow, like:

```css
#outer {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #444000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

#inner {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #333000;
  width: 99px;
  height: 99px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

You can of course specify these properties with jQuery as well, but primarily you need to understand this in CSS and HTML before you apply changes on the structure/design via jQuery.